# Send email via SMTP of gmail through proxy localhost

Tags: php, laravel, email, proxy, smtp

I'm building a laravel website with simple email sending functionality. I can't get my email sending work. I've been doing a lot of email sending before (PHP /Laravel) but this time, i'm super stuck with my current set up. I already used Mailtrap,SMTP gmail,mailgun, sendmail of XAMPP, sendmail of laragon but none of them get to work. I am just trying to send mail to my test gmail account on my localhost but the error keep showing

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed 
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of 
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed 
>   to respond.(10060)

Since i am not directly connected to the internet, i'm suspecting my proxy server. Is there some kind of configuration to be set up on my machine? already try some bunch of tutorial but don't get any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that our proxy server is blocking all SMTP. We cannot use any outside smtp. We need to contact our admin to allow Gmail SMTP.

Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

You can send emails from your localhost using your gmail account
But you need to first create an app password in your [Google Account settings](https://myaccount.google.com/)

1. Choose [Sign-in & Security](https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security)
2. If you are logged in scroll down and find the section **Signing in to Google** and click on **App Passwords** in the box to the right
3. Generate app password using **Select the app and device you want to generate the app password for** form. Select App, Select Device and click Generate. You should see a password generated.
4. Configure your *.env* file to look like this:

   `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
   MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
   MAIL_PORT=587
   MAIL_USERNAME=youremailusername
   MAIL_PASSWORD=generated-password
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Run `php artisan config:clear`
and you should now be able to send email form localhost if your Mail sending code is okay and you are connected to the internet.

Comment: Tried already, but it seems that my proxy is affecting my email sending functionality

Comment: Are you sure you have run the `php artisan config:clear` command. Because configuration might have been cached.

Comment: Yeah. i found an article that says probably my proxy is blocking all smtp thats why i cannot send outside mails.